# move up/down in jquery

Tags: jquery

I Have 5 spans i am trying to move them up/down (swap positions) in jquery

```
<a href="#" id="up">Up!</a> 
<a href="#" id="down">Down!</a>

<span id='1'>Test1</span><br>
<span id='2'>Test2</span><br>
<span id='3'>Test3</span><br>
<span id='4'>Test4</span><br>
<span id='5'>Test5</span>
```

i have tryed but nothing is happening.

```
 $("#"+LinkID).insertBefore($("#"+LinkID).next('span'));
```

Comment: By the way, your IDs are invalid. They may not start with a digit

Comment: @Harmen - given how many are adopting, you should be specific now, they're invalid *in HTML4* (not HTML5) :)

Comment: @Nick, I didn't know that. I think I still prefer stricter specs of HTML4 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to insert a certain span before the next one, which makes it remain on the same position...

```
$("#"+LinkID).insertBefore($("#"+LinkID).prev());
```

or

```
$("#"+LinkID).insertAfter($("#"+LinkID).next());
```

would be better.

Comment: And to save jQuery the trouble of finding `$("#"+LinkID)` more than once, it is better to store it I.E: `var $link = $("#"+LinkID); $link.insertBefore($link.prev());`

Comment: @Gully, it works, I've tested it myself. But maybe you should use a list with `<ul>` s and `<li>` s instead. These `<br>` s are elements too, which makes it a little complicated.

Comment: `<span><br>` is simply awkward, `<ul><li>` works but the simplest is just `<div>`

Comment: @generalhenry : I mostly agree, but it depends on the context. If these are a set of related items then they *are* a list, and if you're re-arranging the order they're probably an *ordered* list, so should be marked up with `<ol><li>`

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're telling a span to go before the next span (i.e., stay the same). Try using insertBefore on a previous or insertAfter with a next.

**EDIT** Try this on for size: http://jsfiddle.net/eJk3R/

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example. Its not styled up well or anything, but clicking on Up or Down inserts that element either before its previous sibling or after its next sibling.

```
<style type="text/css">
    span.swapMe {
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }
</style>

<span class="swapMe">Test1 <span class="up">Up!</span> <span class="down">Down!</span></span>
<span class="swapMe">Test2 <span class="up">Up!</span> <span class="down">Down!</span></span>
<span class="swapMe">Test3 <span class="up">Up!</span> <span class="down">Down!</span></span>
<span class="swapMe">Test4 <span class="up">Up!</span> <span class="down">Down!</span></span>
<span class="swapMe">Test5 <span class="up">Up!</span> <span class="down">Down!</span></span>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("span.up").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().insertBefore($(this).parent().prev())
});

$("span.down").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().insertAfter($(this).parent().next())
});


</script>
```