# Move containing elements up and down with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Thanks for any help you can provide! Currently, I use a ui-sortable code to allow users to move items up and down in order. Now, I want to give each of these items a set of "up" and "down" buttons that allow users to move items up and down with a click. I've tried reworking theses posts, but I seem to be missing something obvious...

[jQuery Sortable Move UP/DOWN Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951941/jquery-sortable-move-up-down-button)
[move up/down in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260373/move-up-down-in-jquery)

I think somehow I'm not applying the jquery to the right element. My jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/kevindp78/vexw5/2/ and code is below.

HTML

```
<div id="box" class="ui-sortable" style="display: block;"> 
<div class="leg">
    <a class="image">IMG1</a>
    <div class="details">
        <h3><a href="/details">Info</a></h3>
        <span class="moreinfo">MoreInfo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="up-down">
        <p>Change Order</p>
        <div class="up">
            <input type="button" value="Up" class="up-button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
            <input type="button" value="down" class="down-button"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="morestuff">
        Stuff1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="leg">
    <a class="image">IMG2</a>
    <div class="details">
        <h3><a href="/details">Info</a></h3>
        <span class="moreinfo">MoreInfo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="up-down">
        <p>Change Order</p>
        <div class="up">
            <input type="button" value="Up" class="up-button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
            <input type="button" value="down" class="down-button"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="morestuff">
        Stuff2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="leg">
    <a class="image">IMG3</a>
    <div class="details">
        <h3><a href="/details">Info</a></h3>
        <span class="moreinfo">MoreInfo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="up-down">
        <p>Change Order</p>
        <div class="up">
            <input type="button" value="Up" class="up-button"/>
        </div>
        <div class="down">
            <input type="button" value="down" class="down-button"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="morestuff">
        Stuff3
    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
$('up-button').click(function(){
$(this).parent('.leg').insertBefore.previous('.leg')
});

$('.down-button').click(function(){
$(this).parent('.leg').insertAfter.next('.leg')
});
```

Comment: Lack of semi-colons are typos right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several problems to address in your code so let's go through them in order.

First there is `$('up-button')` it is missing the [`.`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) so it won't select the buttons.

Next you are using the [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method which only goes up one level, use [`parents('.leg')`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead.

[`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) is a method that accepts a target as to where to place the content you selected.

`previous()` isn't a function, it is [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead and it doesn't need a parameter as it just selects the previous element.

If you combine all of those fixes you would get something like this

```
$('.up-button').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.leg').insertBefore($(this).parents('.leg').prev());
});

$('.down-button').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.leg').insertAfter($(this).parents('.leg').next());
});
```

As demonstrated on this edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vexw5/6/

Comment: While it wasn't the first response, it was the most informative and detailed so that I could learn where I went wrong (and there was a lot to learn!) Thank you, @BeardFist.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for an elegant and concise solution! +1

Answer (score 8):

You could try replacing your JS with something like this:

```
$(".down").click(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parents(".leg");
    $parent.insertAfter($parent.next()); 
});

$(".up").click(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parents(".leg");
    $parent.insertBefore($parent.prev()); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vexw5/7/

This is just the basics. There are no animations or anything.

Comment: I gave the correct answer to @BeardFist because it offered more detail as to the errors I had made. I really appreciate your solution as well; thanks for taking the time to help me.