# How to implement item movement (up and down) using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have following task and explained through below image

[image]

where I would like to implement functionality of up and down using arrows. **I have implemented movement of element using Drag and Drop (using jQuery Sortable)** but not getting idea how to perform up and down movement of item using arrows?

How to implement it jQuery (front and a related MySQL query in back end)?
What should be good query creating while user clicks on up or down arrow?

**Note:**

FYI every item is wrapped in `<div>` tag.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about jquery Sortable? http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default

Comment: @Pavlo, yes I do have used sortable for Drag and Drop. But not getting idea how to do with arrows?

Comment: I would assume http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/ and http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/ should work

Comment: who is wrapped in `<div>` ? every item ?

Comment: Also please check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485859/move-containing-elements-up-and-down-with-jquery       And the fiddle from that post http://jsfiddle.net/vexw5/6/

Comment: @Saurabh, `Item 1` is wrapped in div tag and each has unique id. That's the mean.

Comment: It's a good idea to include the html code you are using. Are you using an `<ul>` or a `<table>` for this?

Comment: @DarkAshelin, I am using `<div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.up-button').click(function(){
  $(this).p1('.my').insertBefore($(this).p1('.my').prev());
});

$('.down-button').click(function(){
  $(this).p1('.my').insertAfter($(this).p1('.my').next());
});
```

i wish may be its help you .you can try this

Comment: I appreciate your answer friend (y)

Comment: Create an orderid in database. When clicking the up / down make an ajax request to change the order id so that the front end automatically refreshes loads new order

Comment: @MACMAN, yes you're right. I have used same for Drag and Drop but was thinking about which values I should send through Ajax when up or down arrow key is pressed?

Comment: Whenever you click the up or down arrow, you have to implement a swap on the server side for orderid. If you move a record from 3rd to 2nd, the order id needs to be swapped between 3 and 2 records.

Comment: nice and simple asswer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used jQuery's `insertBefore` ,`insertAfter` and `detach` methods to do demo

PLease check the [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/52c9Z/2/) for more explanation

Comment: You explained like charm ;) (y) and your example exactly solving my problem. So I am going to just implement it and as soon as I will accept an answer. One word "Awesome!"

Comment: Now I just have to prepare on query that how it should update order in DB Table.

Comment: @NullPointer have a col in DB table that indicates the order and in click events fire a ajax calls that increments or decrements order accordingly