# Preventing element moving too far up DOM in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to write a form where a user can move items up and down to reorder the inputs.  The items come from a symfony collection which too much to show here but the basic idea is shown below.

I took the js from [Move containing elements up and down with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485859/move-containing-elements-up-and-down-with-jquery).  It moves them up and down but ideally I would like to:

1. Prevent the top item from moving further beyond the top or bottom text.
2. Hide the up arrow for the topmost item and the down arrow for the bottom item (I guess doing this would actually solve 1?).

I'm fairly new to js and can't quite figure the solution.

Thanks in advance for any help - please let me know if I can make things clearer.  I have a working jsfiddle here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martynwheeler/xrfhud56/22/)

```js
$('.js-up').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('div.js-item').insertBefore($(this).parents('div.js-item').prev());
});

$('.js-down').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('div.js-item').insertAfter($(this).parents('div.js-item').next());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  Can't go above here
</div>
<div class="js-item form-row">
  1. Moveable text
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-up btn btn-primary float-right" title="up"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-down btn btn-primary float-right" title="down"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="js-item form-row">
  2. Moveable text
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-up btn btn-primary float-right" title="up"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-down btn btn-primary float-right" title="down"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="js-item form-row">
  3. Moveable text
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-up btn btn-primary float-right" title="up"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-down btn btn-primary float-right" title="down"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  Can't go below here
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the parent selector to `prev()` and `next()`.  If the prev/next element does not match that selector, nothing moves.

```js
function itemMoved () {
  $('.first-item, .last-item').removeClass('first-item last-item');
  $('div.js-item')
    .first().addClass('first-item').end()
    .last().addClass('last-item');
}

$('.js-up').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('div.js-item').insertBefore($(this).parents('div.js-item').prev('div.js-item'));
  itemMoved();
});

$('.js-down').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('div.js-item').insertAfter($(this).parents('div.js-item').next('div.js-item'));
  itemMoved();
});

itemMoved();
```

```css
.first-item .fa-arrow-up, .last-item .fa-arrow-down {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  Can't go above here
</div>
<div class="js-item form-row">
  1. Moveable text
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-up btn btn-primary float-right" title="up"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-down btn btn-primary float-right" title="down"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="js-item form-row">
  2. Moveable text
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-up btn btn-primary float-right" title="up"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-down btn btn-primary float-right" title="down"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="js-item form-row">
  3. Moveable text
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-up btn btn-primary float-right" title="up"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a href="#" class="js-down btn btn-primary float-right" title="down"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  Can't go below here
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  Any idea how I could address 2 to make the form look neater too please?  I guess I need to look and if it is the first element and hide the up button and if the last element hide the down button.

Comment: @MartynW modified the logic to use two classes added to the elements to hide the arrows when needed.